# How to extract the string from certain character using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am new to programming. i want to extract string from particular character.

Consider the below string.

```
'<sometext id="2" name="username"/>hello'
```

I want to retrieve the  "username" and text  after /> which is "hello"

so basically i have this string as a value for an object property so something like

```
object  = {
              property_1: "<sometext id=\"2\" name=\"username\"/>hello",
          }
```

so i retrieve it using object.string_to_parse and store it in variable string_to_parse

```
let string_to_parse = object.property_1;
```

Now i want to get the string "username" from string_to_parse and store it in a separate variable and string "hello" from string_to_parse and store it in another variable.

How can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Currently your code is a syntax error; quote characters (`"`) have to be quoted with a backslash when inside a string made with the same quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution to use here would be to split that string up and store the parts you need. Like such:

```js
let object  = {
  property_1: "<sometext id='2' name='username'/>hello",
};
let string_to_parse = object.property_1;
let prop1;
let prop2;

prop1 = string_to_parse.split("name='")[1].split("'/")[0];
prop2 = string_to_parse.split('/>')[1];

console.log(prop1);
console.log(prop2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex should do the trick:

```
var str = '<sometext id="2" name="username"/>hello';

var re = /name="([^"]*)"/g
match = re.exec(str);
var uname = match[1];

var re = /\/>(.*)$/g
match = re.exec(str);
var msg = match[1];
```

The uname and msg variables have what you are trying to extract

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you have only one or multiple ones of your separator `"/>"`.
if we suppose we only have one you can get it with:

```
object.property_1.split("/>")[1]
```

The `split` method helps you return 2 elements, one containing the string before the separator (here `">"`) and one containing the string after the separator.

Using this method you can easily get your username string, so I'll let you do this one yourself.